# Is it safe to cap off live red wire in split receptacle?

Tags: electrical, wiring, kitchens, electrical-panel, code-compliance

Ontario, Canada.
Kitchen has a split receptacle with 2 hot wires (black and red). The metal tab on the receptacle (on the side of black/red wires) is broken off. There is a combined 20amp breaker at the electrical panel.

I am trying to install a [USB charger receptacle](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B01N4AXO6J), but it has just neutral, hot and ground terminals.

Is it safe to simply cap off the red wire, tape it up nicely, and push it to the back of the gang box?

I am not comfortable changing the breaker on the electrical panel.

Comment: Are there just 3 wires in 1 cable coming into the box? (Besides ground).

Comment: @Harper yes, single Romex cable with 3 wires + ground

Comment: The red has nothing to do with the breaker. It's split in the room at the switch.

Comment: By "Combined breaker" do you mean a two-pole breaker?

Comment: @isherwood I recall reading somewhere that Canada requires kitchen SABCs to be MWBCs

Comment: @isherwood there is no switch, there are 2 live 120v wires (red and black), one feeding the top, the other feeding the bottom

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is fine to do but against code because that plug is required to be split to meet code rules for kitchen counter tops.

CEC 26-712(d)(iii)

Comment: This answer could use a fair bit of expansion, and a Code quote would be a nice finishing touch :)

Comment: Thanks. For a home owner, what's the consequence of not being to code?

Comment: Code quote is in the comment. Consequence is when you go to sell a diligent home inspector for a potential purchaser could call you on it and also if the house should burn down or something else it could be held against you.

Comment: Are you sure about the requirement for a split receptacle?